# targeting h2::after containing a h2::before

Tags: css, pseudo-element

how to to apply some css specifically to the h2::after that also have a h2::before ?

```
.region-sidebar-second .block > h2::after, .region-content .block > h2:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
  margin-top: 0.75rem;
  border: 0.5px solid #252525;
  position: relative;
}

#block-block-51 h2::before{
  padding-right: 5px;
  content: "\f02d";
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro",sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
}

::after_selector_for_those_h2_that_have_a_::before{
   left:2rem;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't, at least not yet. That would require a selector which selects elements that have a `before` pseudo element, which doesn't exist. Selectors only work on what is available in the DOM.

There is a working draft that would enable this with the [pseudo-class selector `:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has). It would look as follows:

```css
element:has(::before)::after
```

But, from the docs:

> In the current specification :has is not marked as part of the live selector profile, which means it can not be used within stylesheets; only with functions like `document.querySelector()`.